# Is it possible to paste a link without tags and make it directly a link in a post?

Tags: posts, comments, post-meta, links

So for example: if I post http://testeteststetetst.com, it won't make it a link if it's a post. If it's comment, it does make it a link... Now, I want it for posts too.. Is this possible, if so, how? Can someone help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a similar method to the following in a plugin of mine:

```
function wpse107488_urls_to_links( $string ) {
    /* make sure there is an http:// on all URLs */
    $string = preg_replace( "/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2", $string );
    /* create links */
    $string = preg_replace( "/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;%#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", "<a target=\"_blank\" title=\"" . __( 'Visit Site', 'your-textdomain' ) . "\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

I don't use it for post content, but it should work there.
For that, you'd have to employ the [`the_content` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse107488_urls_to_links' );
```

Sidenotes:
This is untested.
The regexes are fairly good, but they will fail in niche cases once in a while. Identifying a URL by format only, while avoiding false positives isn't the simplest of things.

Comment: Nope, it is nothing working... Of course I mean with that: it breaks my other non-http links. For example, I have inline links that link to posts (which don't use http but a shortcode), but now, with this function, it gives them also an http:// and a title, and here, the title is visible in the post instead in the hover...

Can you enhance the code?

Comment: It does what it has to do, so it makes a link of http:// code, but the inline links without http:// are getting http:// before them and a title in the text... can you write an exception for http:// only?